# Null, int? and lambda expressions with EF 4.1

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-4, lambda

I am using an int? variable in a lambda expression, but the generated SQL does contain "IS NULL" when the variable is null.

I have this method in an MVC project using EntityFramework 4.1:

```
public Member GetByEmailAndOrganisationId(string email, int? organisationId)
{
    var member = memberRepository.GetSingleOrDefault(m => m.Email == email && m.OrganisationId == organisationId);

    return member;
}
```

However, when I use SQL-Profiler, I can see that the generated WHERE clause is as follows:

```
WHERE ([Extent1].[Email] = @p__linq__0) AND ([Extent1].[OrganisationId] = @p__linq__1),
@p__linq__0 nvarchar(4000), @p__linq__1 int, 
@p__linq__0=N'jf@beauchamp.me', @p__linq__1=NULL
```

Hence, member is always null in the above code since the WHERE clause contains OrganisationId = NULL instead of OrganisationId IS NULL.

I thought I had solved the problem by using Equals() as follows:

var member = memberRepository.GetSingleOrDefault(m => m.Email == email && m.OrganisationId.Equals(organisationId));

But then I get another error when organisationId is not null:

> Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported
>   in this context.

What is the most elegant way to solve this?

Comment: Where is the `OrganisationId = NULL` in the WHERE clause?

Comment: @univerio [Extent1].[OrganisationId] = \@p__linq__1 and \@p__linq__1=NULL, so we have [Extent1].[OrganisationId] = NULL in the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will do the trick:

```
if(organisationId.HasValue)
    return memberRepository.GetSingleOrDefault(m => m.Email == email && m.OrganisationId == organisationId);
else
    return memberRepository.GetSingleOrDefault(m => m.Email == email && m.OrganisationId == null);
```

It seems to be fixed in EF 4.5: http://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-ado-net-entity-framework-ef-feature-suggestions/suggestions/1015361-incorrect-handling-of-null-variables-in-where-cl?ref=title#suggestion-1015361